# How to use a second-order similarity vector?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I am reading the paper "[Cultural Shift or Linguistic Drift? Comparing Two
Computational Measures of Semantic Change](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02821.pdf)". In the section "Local neighborhood measure" (Page 3) they have used `second-order similarity vector` for comparison.

I understand that they are trying to measure the how many neighbours have changed. However, as I understand this could also be done using `first-order difference`. What I am not clear is why they are using `second-order similarity vector` and the reason is not specified in the paper.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.